# Will Grand Archivist cast a targetable spell if there are no targets available?

Tags: hearthstone

If I play [Grand Archivist](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Grand_Archivist) and the only spell I have in my deck is [Mind Control](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Mind_Control), and there are no enemy minions, then will the Mind Control still be cast at the end of the turn, and removed from my deck?

Because if Mind Control is removed from my deck with no targets, then the spell is essentially destroyed, which makes it a pretty big loss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tested this myself.

I played Grand Archivist with no minions on the enemy's side, and with two Mind Controls as the only spells in my deck.

At the end of my turn, the symbol on Archivist animated as usual, to indicate that it activates, but then nothing happened. **Mind Control was *not* cast.**

Therefore, this actually makes Grand Archivist far better than I thought, because I'm running the card with only Free from Amber and Mind Control. So, if the opponent has no cards on their side, then Free from Amber will always be played. Otherwise if there are minions on the opponent's side, then it's essentially a 50-50 on if Free from Amber or Mind Control is cast.

I also tested that **Grand Archivist will *not* play Mind Control if the only minion that the opponent has is untargetable**.

Comment: I believe the Archivist can still cast mind control on minions that are untargetable. I believe it's a similar interaction to the ogres being able to avoid taunts. I'll check some time and post it here

Comment: On the other hand though, I don't think Noggenfogger targest untargetable minions. It can bypass taunts too, but it otherwise follows the rules, such as your own minions can't hit your own face.

Comment: I'm pretty positive noggenfogger with spells can target untargettable things. I'm 100% certain you can attack stealthed minions for instance

Comment: I just tested and confirmed that Grand Archivist will not cast Mind Control on an untargetable minion.

Comment: Also, Noggenfogger doesn't allow for illegal targeting, per the notes [here](https://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Mayor_Noggenfogger). So it will never target stealthed or untargetable minions with spells.

Comment: Awesome on the untargetable spells, but minions with noggenfogger DO hit stealthed minions. Spells do not. Just tested that. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: Oh right, attack works differently than spells for Noggen.